# Merging, reindexing, or otherwise binning based on an offset month sequence (arbitrary date ranges)

Tags: python, pandas

**Core problem**: I have a finite sequence of months which can have *arbitrary start dates* based on the initial date, e.g. a "month" may defined as Jan 4 - Feb 3, and so on. I have a bunch of labeled time series data that I'd like to put into these month bins. The sequence of months is taken as a given, regardless of the starting date; if the sequence starts on 2018-8-17 then each subsequent month must start on the 17th.

**Example data**

For a sequence of months defined by these start dates:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-02-15', '2012-03-15', '2012-04-15', '2012-05-15',
               '2012-06-15', '2012-07-15', '2012-08-15', '2012-09-15',
               '2012-10-15', '2012-11-15', '2012-12-15', '2013-01-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: kwds={'months': 1}>')
```

And a data set to be matched that looks like:

```
pd.DataFrame([
        [date(2012, 3, 17), 10, 'A'],
        [date(2012, 4, 2), 10, 'A'],
        [date(2012, 4, 17), 10, 'A'],
    ],
    columns=['date', 'value', 'label'],
)
```

The values in this dataframe should be merged or binned to match the defined months, e.g. resulting in something like

```
[
    [date(2012, 3, 15), 20, 'A'],
    [date(2012, 4, 15), 10, 'A']
]
```

Albeit in a dataframe!

**Why not regroup by month or use count of day offsets?**

It's worth noting that the month range is based on a month offset (e.g. `relativedelta(months=1)` such that if the first month starts on May 31, the next month would start on June 30, and the month start after Jan 31 would start Feb 28. The upshot of this is that using day offsets is unhelpful. I haven't yet figured out if there's a way to regroup based on this kind of month definition.

There are probably a few ways to approach this problem. I've created an index using separate start and end dates for the primary date sequence which in SQL could be joined against using comparisons, but unfortunately don't see [yet?] how that's possible in Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
dateidx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2012-02-15', '2012-03-15', '2012-04-15', '2012-05-15',
               '2012-06-15', '2012-07-15', '2012-08-15', '2012-09-15',
               '2012-10-15', '2012-11-15', '2012-12-15', '2013-01-15'])
df_time = pd.DataFrame(index=dateidx)
df_time = df_time.reset_index()

df_values = pd.DataFrame([
        [datetime.date(2012, 3, 17), 10, 'A'],
        [datetime.date(2012, 4, 2), 10, 'A'],
        [datetime.date(2012, 4, 17), 10, 'A'],
    ],
    columns=['date', 'value', 'label'],
)
df_values['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_values.date)
```

Merge and groupby:

```
df_merged = pd.merge_asof(df_values, df_time, left_on='date', right_on='index')
df_merged.groupby(['index','label'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()
```

Output:

```
       index label  value
0 2012-03-15     A     20
1 2012-04-15     A     10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a range as a DateTimeIndex that has that type of end of the month day boundary.

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/31/2012', periods=120, freq='M')
```

then rng would be

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-31', '2012-02-29', '2012-03-31', '2012-04-30', '2012-05-31', '2012-06-30', '2012-07-31', '2012-08-31', '2012-09-
30', '2012-10-31', '2012-11-30','2012-12-31', '2013-01-31', '2013-02-28', '2013-03-31', '2013-04-30', '2013-05-31', '2013-06-30', '2013-07-31', '2013-08-
31', '2013-09-30', '2013-10-31',...
```

A key point is to find a month with 31 days and go with that date.

Comment: "A key point is to find a month with 31 days and go with that date."

I should clarify the problem statement, but start dates can be arbitrary, by month or date. The 'year' could start January 1 or March 23, with all months following from there.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't try the solution using different dates.